# Python file contents to be read by another python file and print the content

Tags: python

python file contents to be read by another python file and print the content

taking 2 python files

one.py

```
print (content of two.py)
```

two.py

```
if any(data):
    print data
    validate()
    random()
```

result:

```
if any(data):
    print data
    print data
    validate()
    random()
```

is that possible

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=python+file+tutorial

Comment: Is this somewhat related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9110159/1132524)? If it is please make one good clear question, not two confused.

Comment: yes am very much confused how to ask that question..i am newbie to python...sorry for troubles

Comment: are you trying to write a quine?

Comment: not quine sort..what i am exactly trying to is create a test case automation...where i had some issue in our earlier model of importing test case data from excel..on discussions now we thought if the test case can be written in test scripts form where the main thread will read the test script thread and interpret the defined functions ...also the test scripts can do actions like direct validations...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute another python program from your python program or from python prompt then you can just import `os` and execute command using `os.system` as below

`One.py` may be as below

```
import os
os.system('./two.py')
#process further
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can:

```
with open("two.py") as two:
    for line in two:
      print line,
```

Comment: is there any way to excute that line